# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)

Tags: pycharm

El tema es que estoy intentando instalar en Pycharm , el tensorflow , pero me saltan estos errores:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

La verdad no sé a que puede ser , el resto de paquetes que he instalado no me ha dado ningún problwma
Ya he actualizado pip.

Comment: Alguien vota cerrar XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todo depende de tu versión de Python. Tensorflow solo funciona con dos condiciones:

- Tienes que tener Python **x64**. No funcionará con una versión de **x32**.
- Tu versión debe ser **3.5** a **3.7**, según leí, ya funciona en versiones **3.8 de 64 bits**.

Espero esta información te haya sido útil.

Answer (score 0):

Pasos para solucionar ese problema:

1. Instalar `Anaconda`.
2. Una vez descargado entrar a `Anaconda Navigator`.
3. En el panel izquierdo (*debajo del Home*) ir a `Environments`.
4. Hacer click en Create, te abre una pestaña en donde debes ingresar el nombre. Hacer click en la casilla de verificación `Python` y colocar la version de `Python 3.8` (yo tenia instalada la *3.9* y por eso no podia instalar `Tensorflow`.
5. Desde el panel izquierdo ir a *Home* nuevamente.
6. Ejecutar `Visual Studio Code` (si no esta instalado primero instalarlo).
7. En la terminal de `VSCode` poner `pip install tensorflow` (siempre hacerlo desde la ruta principal, ejemplo: *C:\Users\nombreusuario* . si por defecto esta en otra ruta poner... *cd C:\Users\nombreusuario\nombreusuario* se refiere al que cada uno tiene en su maquina).

**LISTO**! si de esta manera no funciona seguramente sea porque no tienes la version correcta de `PIP`.

Intente de miles de formas y esta fue la única que me funciono.

Saludos!